# Can an 85w MagSafe charger (model#: A1172) be used safely with a MBPro 13.3” retina?

Tags: magsafe

I’ve read through a few threads on here on this subject - which give very detailed information - but just wish to ask, by way a safety/ sanity check, the following...

I have a MacBook Pro 13” Retina display (early 2013), which uses a Magsafe 2 60w charger.

The original, 60w charger has failed and I wish to confirm whether this charger I have will be safe to use with my MB Pro:

- Apple 85w MagSafe charger for MacBook Pro. 
  Model#: A1172
  Input: 100-240V-1.5A 50-60Hz
  Output: 18.5V 4.6A

Link: [full charger specs here >>](https://www.thebookyard.com/product.php?manufacturers_id=25&products_id=2382)

I have this from an earlier model MBPro I had.

If I wire this up, by soldering a Magsafe 2 replacement power cord to the board, will this work safely with the MBPro 13”?

Despite the info’ on other threads here confirming that it’s fine to use a 85w MagSafe with a mac that normally uses a 60w charger, I’m unsure whether this one will be safe due to it being an older model than those refered to; ie. older, larger/ rectangular model rather than the more recent square ones.

Would this be safe/ compatible despite this?

Thanks greatly for any help with - best wishes, AE

Comment: Btw. I read through on this, and similar threads here - so have that info - it’s just that I want to check re. this ‘specific’ 85w charger and whether it would be safe to use with the MBPro 13” as described above. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/can-i-use-45-60-85w-macbook-chargers-interchangeably

Comment: Indeed, on a level I expect, but with the caveat I was asking about this specific model of charger: #A1172

Comment: Apologies if there’s any transgression of the forum rules in that, I’m new obviously.