# Charging MacBook Pro (Mid 2014, 13") with third-party charger and USB-C to MagSafe2 adapter

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, charging, magsafe, charger

The 60W MagSafe 2 charger of my MacBook Pro (Mid 2014, 13") is already pretty worn down, and the cables are almost broken. A replacement is costly, and I think I'd prefer a charger with a detachable cable, as I fear the original one might break easily again when I carry it around in my bagpack. I'm thinking of buying a third-party USB-C charger, and then using a USB-C->MagSafe2 adapter to connect it to the MacBook. From what I've seen, [using a higher wattage charger is discouraged](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/449827/can-you-safely-use-any-higher-wattage-magsafe1-charger-on-any-macbook), especially if the MacBook doesn't natively support USB-C, as is the case here. Most third-party chargers I've seen have 65W, I guess that shouldn't make too much of a difference.

I feel like this should be possible, but I know Apple is rather particular about using non-Apple hardware and accessories. Do I have to expect any damage to my MacBook using a third-party charger and USB-C to MagSafe2 adapter, or should this work just fine (as long as the charger specs match)?

I don't think my question is a duplicate. Most questions refer to MacBooks that **already handle USB-C natively, which is not the case here, as USB-C was released *after* this MacBook came up**. Do the remarks regarding "power negotiation" then still apply? I would assume not.

Comment: Using a higher wattage charger is perfectly fine.  The answer you linked to references *voltage* not wattage.  It’s also irrelevant.  USB-C negotiates the power that’s delivered.

Comment: Does the USB-C charger does that on its own? Or does the connected device need to support some interface?

Comment: USB-C charging is standards compliant meaning they must comply with the industry defined methods for charging.  As along as you get a something that says USB-PD (for Power Delivery), it will work.  All Apple products are USB-PD compliant.